# Can card.io scan card number from image in file

Tags: card.io

I read the description card.io SDK on the website. There is described scan using the device's camera.

Is it possible to scan card number with card.io from image in file?

Answer (score 1):

Dave from card.io here.

Sorry, but card.io can only scan actual credit cards, via a live mobile camera. It cannot scan images from files.